# Swift - Add two array elements to detailTextLabel in tableView

Tags: ios, swift

I have a tableview with a list of students. Each cell contains the name of a student and a subtitle. I managed to add two elements to my subtitle by creating a constant and returning this data.

**I am trying to display this:**

(Textlabel) First Student

(Subtitle) Elementary, 5th grade

**I am currently using this piece of code:**

```
let subTitle = "\(student.level)\(", ")\(student.grade)"

cell!.detailTextLabel?.text = subTitle
```

**Is it wise to do it like this? It's working, but I am not sure if this the best method.**

*Extended version of my code:*

```
studentArray = [
        Student(level: "Elementary", grade: "5th grade", name: "First student"),
        Student(level: "Junior High", grade: "3rd grade", name: "Second student"),
        Student(level: "High School", grade: "1st grade", name: "Third student")


// Return results
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellId")
    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cellId")
    }

    let student: Student

    if searchController.active && (searchController.searchBar.text != "" || !filteredStudents.isEmpty) {
        student = filteredStudents[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        student = studentArray[indexPath.row]
    }

    cell!.textLabel?.text = student.name
    cell!.textLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14)

    cell!.textLabel?.text = student.name
    cell!.textLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14)

    let subTitle = "\(student.level)\(", ")\(student.grade)"

    cell!.detailTextLabel?.text = subTitle
    cell!.detailTextLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10)

    return cell!
}
```

Comment: Looks ok to me, however, this is more of a code review less code issue, not sure if this is the right place.

Comment: ya your code is fine

Comment: I agree, so I wasn't really sure about posting this question in the first place.

However, I thought it would be useful to others who might have the same question and are looking for something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

then alternate Way try this

```
   var subTitle = "\(student.level)"
    subTitle += ",\(student.grade)"
```

or use like

```
 let subTitle = "\(student.level),\(student.grade)"
```

finally append like

```
cell!.detailTextLabel?.text = subTitle
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that looks good except your string is a little squirrely. Here's is how I'd simplify it:

```
let subTitle = "\(student.level), \(student.grade)" // Elementary, 5th grade
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)